PcapPlusPlus cross compilation
I use the PcapPlusPlus library to craft packets and use them in my unit tests for my C application. These packets are not sent over the network. I just use functions to create/add protocol headers and then get a pointer to raw data of such packet. That's all. The library requires libpcap so I installed on my Linux to be able to compile it locally and run tests on my machine.
Now I'm trying to compile the PcapPlusPlus library using ARM compiler, to run unit tests in QEMU on ARM arch. Since it requires libpcap library, I added to my cmake the fetch declaration to clone and build libpcap sources from GitHub repository. Not sure whether including libpcap to the cmake file would help. With this approach I'm getting following error when it tries to compile the fetched sources:
C99 support is required, but the compiler doesn't support a compiler flag to enable it

The flag it complains about is std-gnu99.

Should I do something to enable C99? Cmake prints info about the compiler and says it's GNU 5.4.0.
Is it correct way to resolve libpcap dependency error? Adding it in the cmake with the fetch declaration would make it available for PcapPlusPlus?
Since I don't send packets over the network, just use the PcapPlusPlus to craft a packet and get raw data of the packet as an input for my C application, do I need libpcap at all? Maybe there's some switch to disable this dependency and I would be able to cross compile it without any problems?


Your cross compiler did not support gnu99. try c99, search gnu99 in the CMakelists.txt and modify it to c99, run the cmake again. Or build with a new version compiler.
libpcap is mandatory fo pcapplusplus, you can not disable it.
